# How to limit TestNG to run just test classes from project test directory

Tags: maven, testng, maven-3

pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="my-suite">
    <test name="tests">
        <packages>
            <package name="com.example.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestNG will scan all classpath for test classes ([PackageUtils # findClassesInPackage](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.testng/testng/6.10/org/testng/internal/PackageUtils.html#findClassesInPackage-java.lang.String-java.util.List-java.util.List-)).
The unwanted tests are coming from a `test-jar` dependency.
How to configure TestNG to look for test classes just in maven project test directory (`src/test/java` compiled to `target/test-classes` by default) ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there is no tests in your classes directory what to worry about?

Secondary, you can change package of your test classes, it also useful for search e.g. com.example.qa.*.

And the third one - you may try to manipulate with your classpath in maven-surefire-plugin, see [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).

Answer (score 0):

We use a pretty nice setup with separate unit tests and integration tests using the surefire and failsafe plugins. I never use suite.xml or similar test suite definitions. You can use includes and excludes with file patterns to control what gets executed. We also use a custom listener because I wanted a bit control over the testoutput and we run tests concurrently, which won't work for you unless you write tests that don't interact, which is always a good idea.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*ApiTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>20</threadCount>
                <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.inbot.testutil.TestProgressLogger,io.inbot.testutil.TestNgRandomizerWithSeed</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <!-- this disables expensive loading of spring
                            context and starting our test server: keep the unit tests fast! any expensive
                            test should end with IntegrationTest or ApiTest. They will be run separately
                            by failsafe plugin -->

                        <name>nointegrationtests</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                    <include>**/*ApiTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.inbot.testutil.TestProgressLogger,io.inbot.testutil.TestNgRandomizerWithSeed</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <systemProperties>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

For TestNG the best way is to use TestNG system property for it.

Add following to your surefire plugin configuration section:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <testng.test.classpath>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</testng.test.classpath>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

This willeffectively limit discovery of tests only to that path (`target/test-classes`).